# SQS numbers high even though I'm not using it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

[image]

Here are my numbers from AWS usage even though I am not using SQS at all in my application.
I have a lambda service (it's not even in production yet) and it talks to external API + My frontend via API Gateway.
How come my SQS usage is so high?
I don't even have any aps in sqs [I used to when I did some tutorials with sqs, but that was a simple feature]. And my guess that S3 is si high because of the SAM deploy.
How can I check what's causing this traffic?

Comment: Is the Request Count still increasing? Also, don't be too worried -- the forecast is saying that you would stay within the Free Tier of 1 million requests (but, yes, it would be nice to know what is happening).

Comment: Yeah, I'm more curious rather than worried.

Comment: Is the Request Count still increasing?

Comment: not at the moment, no :)

Comment: In that case, the usage was probably related to your tutorial.

Comment: Well actually it went up by a few requests [10] over the night

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. I had created few SQS queues and used only once for testing with few messages. One day I got an alert from AWS saying my SQS free tier consumption had crossed 85% usage. SQS provides 1 million messages free. I was shocked to learn that around 850K messages were consumed.

I found out that if a lambda function is setup to be triggered by SQS event, then lambda will continuously poll the queue for messages. It will get `NumberOfEmptyReceives` event if there are no messages in the queue.

Now there are 2 kinds of polling supported, *short* and *long*. But by default lambda does short polling. You can opt for long polling but that too has max limit of 20 seconds, after which it will poll the queue for messages.

The solution is to remove the **event source mappings** between lambda and the SQS if you're not using it. This will stop the polling and the surge of messages.

Comment: I had the exact same process happen and came to the same conclusion as well. At first I was confused because Cloudwatch was showing only a small number of messages being processed, but when I graphed the NumberOfEmptyReceives I could see each queue with a Lambda trigger was getting nearly 9000 requests per day. With 5 SQS/Lambda triggers, I was going over the free tier by about 345k requests per month, yielding a $0.20 charge per month (so quite small). Since a few of these were for an old project I was able to clean up some of the triggers to eliminate this charge

Answer (score 1):

You presumably do have, or did have, some SQS queues. See [Monitoring Amazon SQS queues using CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-monitoring-using-cloudwatch.html).

> Amazon SQS and Amazon CloudWatch are integrated so you can use CloudWatch to view and analyze metrics for your Amazon SQS queues. You can view and analyze your queues' metrics from the Amazon SQS console, the CloudWatch console, using the AWS CLI, or using the CloudWatch API. You can also set CloudWatch alarms for Amazon SQS metrics.

Also, see [Why are my Amazon SQS charges higher than expected?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sqs-high-charges/)

Comment: I have none when I go to SQS

Comment: None, in any region? Any chance that you have launched SAM projects (that have SQS queues) and later terminated them (deleting the queues with them)? You should be able to use CloudTrail to detect API calls against SQS.

Comment: I went manually through all of the regions and they are all empty.
There was one or two projects that I did that, but I removed manually that queue.